# App with workflows hangs "Your Apps" page

Tags: 2013, workflow, app

I have an app with two workflows. The app is SharePoint hosted. Once I add the .app file to the global catalog the "Your Apps" page hangs on "loading" when I open it.

If I remove the workflows it works fine.

SharePoint 15.0.4631.1000 (July CU)
Workflow Manager 1.0 Refresh CU2

Everything except AD and SQL runs on the same server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

The problem was that somehow my WF databases had gotten removed. Reconfiguring Workflow Manager rebuilt the databases and now it works.